# Better solution for making on-screen keyboard

Tags: c#, winforms, on-screen-keyboard

I'm trying to make on-screen keyboard (button <kbd>A</kbd>, button <kbd>B</kbd>, etc).
When you press button it does add character to `TextBox`.

Everything is working fine but if i will create like 30+ chars my code will be huge.

Any possible way to make it shorter? Code at the moment for 3 buttons.

```
// Method for each button
private void tastaturasIevade(TextBox varda_ievade, string burts)
{
    if (varda_ievade.TextLength == 0)
    {
        varda_ievade.Text = burts;
    }
    else
    {
        varda_ievade.Text = varda_ievade.Text + burts;
    }
}

// Writing buttons from on-screen keyboard
private void btn_A_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tastaturasIevade(txt_VardaIevade, "a");
}

private void btn_B_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tastaturasIevade(txt_VardaIevade, "b");
}

private void btn_C_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tastaturasIevade(txt_VardaIevade, "c");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you even needs to write code? As a better and more logical solution you can use the [on-screen keyboard application that comes with windows](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/type-with-the-on-screen-keyboard) for this purpose:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("osk.exe");
```

Comment: This is quite nice. Still i want to write my own. But thanks for this!

Comment: And for w8 and above, you can just enable focus tracking and it works like a touch application.  See [How can I make the touch keyboard appear automatically when focus enters an edit control in my program?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150601-00/?p=45481)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is. You can set the "Tag"-Property of the Controls manually, then apply the same Handler to all the Click-Events and add the Content of the "Tag" to the TextBox accordingly.

```
TextBox.Text += (string)(((Button)sender).Tag);
```

Comment: You can use .Text as well since it is the character your are "typing." I'd use the .Tag as a flag to allow upper case or not then iterate over all with a .ToUpper or .ToLower to deal with Shift. Also you can tie all "keys" to the same click event and just use the Sender.Text as the value.

Comment: I like the idea, though I doubt it'd really work out because some keys need to store up to 3 different characters, making this approach harder. It's easier to just store all the characters in the Tag-Property and then append the first, second or third character in the .Tag-Property, according to which modifier keys are active.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `tag` property for each button in the designer to the corresponding text. Then, under your form initialize event, add a single event handler for all the buttons. In `tastaturasIevade` method use the `tag` property of the button.

Answer (score 0):

Simple example using .Text of the keys. A .Tag="c" is a character. More complex tags can be used for logic flow. btnQ is the only named button in the simple example. Shift has a dedicated click event.

```
Sub ShiftCaseLower()
    For Each c As Control In FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls
        If c.Tag = "c" Then c.Text = c.Text.ToLower
    Next
End Sub
Sub ShiftCaseUpper()
    For Each c As Control In FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls
        If c.Tag = "c" Then c.Text = c.Text.ToUpper
    Next
End Sub
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click, Button6.Click, Button5.Click, Button4.Click, Button3.Click, btnQ.Click
    ' all "key" click events handled here
    TextBox1.AppendText(sender.text)
End Sub
Private Sub Button9_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button9.Click
    ' Shift key
    If Asc(btnQ.Text) = Asc("Q") Then
        ShiftCaseLower()
    Else
        ShiftCaseUpper()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry this is VB, I don't speak C#.